# Apache configuration for Jekyll sites

Tags: apache, jekyll

When I run Jekyll locally `bundle exec jekyll serve` I noticed that I can browse my video for example http://127.0.0.1:4000/videos/towards-holistic-approach. The URL does not have `.html` extension but it works.

When I upload the Jekyll `_site` directory to my Apache server these URL's do not work. The URL only works if I manually add `.html` to it for example https://mydomain/videos/towards-holistic-approach

How do I configure Apache to serve Jekyll sites?

Btw, I found this already https://www.askapache.com/htaccess-file/htaccess/src-richarizardd-made-mistakes-jekyll-master-htaccess/

Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case. I tried for example

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

This does help for https://mydomain/videos/towards-holistic-approach but after the change I will be unable to access the root of my site for example https://mydomain no longer works.

I now think that Jekyll does require very specific Apache configuration to function well but https://jekyllrb.com/ does not provide any information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a fresh Centos7 , apache environment.
Solved it while setting the `Multiviews` Option in the vhost:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

I found the description in the permalink section of the jekyllrb.com docs: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#apache